# How does yaml-cpp reorder the nodes when saving?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

When rewriting a `.yaml` file, the nodes get reordered. I can't seem to figure out how it reorders them and what the pattern is. Does anyone know how the reordering is done?

Here is the code to rewrite the `.yaml` file:

```
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");
config["lastLogin"] = getCurrentDateTime();
std::ofstream fout("config.yaml");
fout << config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look inside the implementation of `Node`, we find that it stores its children in a `std::map<Node*, Node*>`, i.e. a map from key node pointers to value node pointers.

Thus, the nodes are ordered by their pointer value (which is pretty much arbitrary and might well change from run to run), and they're written in that order too.

Comment: Any idea how it can be saved in order?